# NgRx Effect - type errors when getting a value for the store then piping into service call

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to construct an `NgRx` effect and I just cannot see what is wrong in this example (and really want to understand)

I have the following

```js
 public loadData = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(myActions.loadData),
            exhaustMap(_ =>
                this.store$.pipe(
                    tap(_ => { this.logger.info(`loadData`)}),
                    select(fromApp.getName),
                    first(),
                    map(name => {
                        from(this.getData(name))
                            .pipe(
                                 map(data => myActions.loadDataSuccess(data)))
                            
                    }),
                    catchError(error => {
                     tap(_ => this.logger.error(`loadData: ${error}`));
                     return of(new myActions.loadDataError(error));
                   })
     ))));


/** Service call **/
private async getData(name: string): Promise<DataState[]> {
     ...
}
```

This is how I interpret (obviously wrong somewhere) the flow..

Inside first `exhaustMap`, I use the `this.store$.pipe` to get an argument I need for my service call. So this the cal to`first` should return a `string` (name).

I then use `map` to "map" this string to the `from(this.getData(name))`. As my `getData` returns a Promise, I use `from` to convert to an `observable`.

I then `pipe` this observable result (an array of data) into another map, where I want to return the effects result, ie an action `loadDataSuccess` containing the server results.

The `catchError` wants to catch any errors from the `map` with the service method call inside of it.

The IDE shows me the following errors

```
    Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'EffectResult<Action>'.
       Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
         Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Action'.ts(2322)
```

I don't know where I have gone wrong (I can't get it right even removing the `catchError`)?

### Update 1

Following @Alif50 suggestion to use a switchMap, and also IDE told me to add a return, and removing the `catchError`. I now have..

```
public loadData  = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(myActions.loadData ),
    exhaustMap(_ =>
      this.store$.pipe(
        tap(_ => { this.logger.info(`loadData`)}),
        select(fromApp.getName),
        first(),
        switchMap(name => {
          return from(this.getData(name))
            .pipe(map(data => myActions.loadDataSuccess(data)));
        }))
     )));
```

which gives no errors, so this is s a step forward, But I am still unable to get the `catchError` to work anywhere. So now I just need to know where to add the `catchError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `map` should be a `switchMap` since we are switching to a new `Observable`.:

```
map(name => { // change this map to a switchMap
 from(this.getData(name))
          .pipe(
              map(data => myActions.loadDataSuccess(data)))
           }),
```

!!!! Edit !!!!

```
public loadData  = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(myActions.loadData ),
    exhaustMap(_ =>
      this.store$.pipe(
        tap(_ => { this.logger.info(`loadData`)}),
        select(fromApp.getName),
        first(),
        switchMap(name => {
          return from(this.getData(name))
            .pipe(
               map(data => myActions.loadDataSuccess(data)),
               // add the catchError here because I think this.getData is the point of failure
               catchError(error => {
                 // You also can't have a tap there like you do
                 // in your catchError
                 // I would prefer this instead of the tap though
                 // this.logger.error(`loadData: ${error}`);
                 return of(new myActions.loadDataError(error)).pipe(
                    // use tap like this !!
                    tap(_ => this.logger.error(`loadData: ${error}`))
                 );
               }),
           );
        }))
     )));
```

Comment: Thanks for that @AliF50, I have added UPDATE1 which is getting close (as well as the switchMap, I needed a return - which the IDE suggested). So first() must return an observable and not a string? But I had to remove the `catchError` to get it to work, so still something not right with that part

Comment: Check out my edit, I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Thankyou! Yes that appears to be the right place - so it needs to be within the same `pipe` as the map for the results. Also correct about the tap not working in there. That is fine but I am curious as to why it does not work (I thought tap was just a "transparent pass through.

Comment: `tap` only works in an Observable stream. In my edit I have shown how to use `tap` in the `catchError` but I prefer to just put the code inside of the body of the `catchError` like I show in the comments.

Comment: Great, thank for that info! I really need to find some course on RgRx so I don't always struggle with chaining operations.